# JQuery keypress function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets

I have the following code which checks if a roll number is valid in the database selected by the postname variable. It was working in an earlier version where I hadn't introduced the second variable postname. But at the moment, this code is not working. What's the error here?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {        //function to check rollno is valid
    $('#roll').keyup(function(event) {  
                    var rolll=$('#roll').val();
                    var postname=$('#post').val();
                    $.get('CheckRollValidity',{roll:rolll},{post:postname},function(responseText) { 
                        $('#status1').text(responseText);         
                    });
                });
    });
```

Servlet

```
        roll = request.getParameter("roll");
        temp = request.getParameter("post");
        table1 = "dbo."+post;
        table2 = "dbo.user_candidates";
        try 
        {
            if (roll.length() < 10 || roll.length() > 10) {
                result = "Please enter your " + len + "-digits roll number.";
                count1 = 1;
            } 
            else if (!roll.matches("[0-9]*")) 
            {
                result = "Please enter digits only";
                count1 = 1;
            }
            if (count1 == 0) 
            {
                 //database work
                 result="OK";
            } 
            else 
            {
                  result = "Error";
            }
         }
         response.setContentType("text/plain");
         response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
         response.getWriter().write(result);
```

Also, can I do the same via ajax, alternatively? Here I don't want the code working on pressing a submit button. Rather the working is happening on keypress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't send two objects, you'll have to use one object with two values otherwise the second object is seen as the argument which should have been the callback

```
$.get('CheckRollValidity',{roll:rolll, post:postname},function(responseText) { 
    $('#status1').text(responseText); 
});
```